# How do I remove Cinnamon?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, cinnamon

Today I installed Cinnamon 1.4 but when I log in to it I can't see any panels, just my background image. Can you tell me how to log in to Unity using the terminal and how to remove Cinnamon?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: installed it using terinal, addded PPA ant then typed: sudo apt-get install cinnamon.

Comment: Isn't this question is out of the scope of askubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your post on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987942)

Boot into Recovery mode and type this for the var/apt/cache error:
`sudo mount -n -o remount /`

Then disable auto login from virtual console by doing the following
`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Some of the lines should look like this

> [SeatDefaults]
>   autologin-guest=false
>   autologin-user=username
>   autologin-user-timeout=0
>   autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
>   greeter-session=unity-greeter
>   user-session=ubuntu

Just put a # before all lines starting with autologin

Then whenever you boot into Ubuntu just change the login to `unity` from the lightdm's login screen options

Also you might want to remove `Cinnamon`
Then type in the terminal

> sudo apt-get --purge autoremove cinnamon

Hope that helps.

Comment: it says that it can't access apt. is there any way to login to Unity from root and then I can fix the rest

Comment: @Alen you can login into `recovery mode` during boot and then use the command. i have no idea how to login into unity.

Comment: I did that, I can't access Terminal in GUI mode

Comment: You mean you selected `recovery mode` during boot then `drop to root shell`?

Comment: when booting your screen should look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/0HoTw.png) then select the recovery mode from the list

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: it says that it cannot lock to var/... somenthing .../apt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3567/discussion-between-ashu-and-alen)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987942

Comment: Though the answer may theoretically correct, It is preferable to put the necessary details here, and put the link for reference