# How do I uninstall Cinnamon?

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments, cinnamon

So I installed the cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 12.10 but now I want to uninstall it. What would the command line(s) be to uninstall it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove Cinnamon?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142533/how-do-i-remove-cinnamon)

Answer (score 13):

I remember something like that

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I uninstalled it by the command mentioned by Enes. But I was still getting notification for updating Cinnamon.

I solved it by using these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
...
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove cinnamon and all the related packages the PPA installed you need first to install PPA-purge: disables a PPA and reverts to official packages.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
```

You can see a little example of how to use PPA-purge http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon --autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .cinnamon.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge cinnamon*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .cinnamon.   filters, so that only packages with keyword cinnamon within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```