# How can I switch from Ubuntu Cinnamon to default Ubuntu?

Tags: cinnamon

I have installed Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04.3 LTS from the official ISO. However, I want to switch from Cinnamon flavor to "unflavored" Ubuntu. How do I do that? Just uninstalling the Cinnamon desktop environment? Or do I also have to install a new desktop environment?

Also, are there any other modifications in Ubuntu Cinnamon that I should change to get to default Ubuntu behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Ubuntu (GNOME flavour) from within any other flavour, is essentially just a couple of commands:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

This will install the task (note the caret `^`) which pulls in all the necessary packages to allow you to login to the Ubuntu GNOME flavour.

You may get prompted with a few questions. For example, it will likely ask if you want to use GDM3 as the login manager - you do.

Once complete, you can reboot and choose the "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on Xorg" session at the login screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as intended. Based on another old post ( https://askubuntu.com/a/381072/1747402 ) I then also removed the Cinnamon packages.